# What does '[^~]+' do?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am reviewing some code that was written before I got to my company and I see this `'[^~]+'` used in a lot of code. To add some context it is a part of a for loop function.

```
DECLARE
    new_parent_id number;
BEGIN

FOR i IN (
    select regexp_substr(:PAGE1_SELECTED, '[^~]+', 1, level) material_num, rownum
    from dual
    connect by regexp_substr(:PAGE1_SELECTED, '[^~]+', 1, level) is not NULL)
LOOP
    if i.ROWNUM = 1 then
        new_parent_id := ASSIGN_NEW_MATERIAL (
            pMATERIAL_NUMBER => i.MATERIAL_NUMBER,
            pASSEMBLY_NAME => :PAGE1_NEW_ASSEMBLY
        );
    else
        ASSIGN_MATERIAL_TO_PARENT (
            pNEW_PARENT_ID => new_parent_id,
            pPART_NUMBER => i.PART_NUMBER
        );
    end if;
END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: The regular expression, `[^~]+`, means one or more characters that are not the tilde character.

Comment: @JeffHolt is that necessary for this function, or what problem does it help me avoid? I ask because, as far as I know, tilde characters are not being used in my tables or queries so I don't know why it needs to be there.

Comment: I'd expect that `:PAGE1_SELECTED` is a tilde-separated string of `material_num` values that this code is parsing.  If you're looking at the values of the bind variables when this code is called to determine that there are no tildes, I'd go back to the application to see if there are different code paths that could produce lists of values.

Comment: @JustinCave you're correct, tildes are automatically produced in the code path to separate strings. I didn't think to look at that until you mentioned it, but now it makes sense. I'll leave it as is then, I just couldn't figure out what it was doing. I appreciate the help. =)

Comment: For explanation you may try https://regex101.com/: paste your regular expression and it will generate readable text of what it is doing. Your query splits list of material into master material and its subcomponents (according to function s' names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect that `:PAGE1_SELECTED` is a tilde-separated string of material_num values that this code is parsing. If you're looking at the values of the bind variables when this code is called to determine that there are no tildes, I'd go back to the application to see if there are different code paths that could produce lists of values.